# Bootstrap 4 card navigation

Tags: bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4 beta you can add a navigation to the card component.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#navigation

But there is actual no working example how to switch between different tabs within a card.

for example, this is not working for me. i have added the javascript file too.

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#foo">Foo</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#bar">Bar</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="foo">FOO</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="bar">BAR</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: solved it: you have to put `data-toggle="tab"` on each ancor tag to enable tabbing

Answer (score 25):

**try like this**

```html
    <div class="card ">
        <div class="card-header"> 
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs pull-right"  id="myTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

learn more about it https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/